# Setting different paginations for different pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two pages on my WordPress driven website.

1st page displays blog posts only a single category 
For example: Category Name = Test

2nd page displays all other blog posts

**What I am trying to archive:**

I want only 5 posts per page to be displayed on the 1st page.

And

I want only 15 posts per page to be displayed on the 2nd page.

Can anyone tell me how to archive this?

Here is the codespec for displaying blog posts only a Test category

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('cat=3&paged='.$paged.'&post_per_page=1'.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?> 
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content-test', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_pagination(); ?>  
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `post_per_page` has a `1` in front of the option, which means if you're asking for 10 items, you're really getting 100 which may make it seem like your pagination is not working. Remove the 1 from `post_per_page=1'.get_option('posts_per_page')`

Comment: It is still not working. If I change the setting in WP backend end Settings --> Reading Settings, then the pagination is applied to both pages... Updated codespec: <?php $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('cat=3&paged='.$paged.'&post_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>

Comment: Right, sorry, I mis-read your original question. For one of these you'll need to not use the `get_option('posts_per_page')`. Have you tried setting the pagination value in settings to 15, that the second page will use, and on the 1st page, replace `get_option('posts_per_page')` with `5`?

Comment: @dKen I found the solution.....

Answer (score 0):

After a long of research here is the solution I achived

```
<?php query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => 2,'cat' => '3','paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),));?>
```

Set the pagination number in 'posts_per_page' => 2,

Set the category from where posts are included in 'cat' => '3'