# WordPress: exclude post category from pagination via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In `WordPress`, I want the pagination to skip certain post categories.

I have two pages with blog posts. One page is the regular `WordPress` blog page. It displays all blog posts except for one category. The second page displays only this one category of blog posts. So far, so good. I `query` this via Elementor and it works just fine.

Now, when I click through the pagination on either of these two blog pages, it will just go through all blog posts.

The result I would like to achieve is that the pagination on the regular blog page skips all posts of that one excluded category `ID 43`. On the second blog page (the one that displays only category `ID 43`), the pagination should only navigate through posts in category `ID 43`.

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856099/setting-different-paginations-for-different-pages-in-wordpress) possible via `functions.php`?

I hide the special category from the blog page like so:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-43' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

**EDIT:**

**I found these two functions for the next and previous links in the `WordPress` documentation: ([1](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/) [2](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/)**)

```
// next
    function next_post_link( $format = '%link &raquo;', $link = '%title', $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
        echo get_next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy );
    }

// previous
    function previous_post_link( $format = '&laquo; %link', $link = '%title', $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
        echo get_previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy );
    }
```

Could I hook into them via `functions.php` and a if `page ID is... query` and use a category name in `$excluded_terms = ''`?

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_filter('pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses');

function exclude_category($query) {

if ( $query->is_home() ) {

$query->set( 'cat', '-43' );
}

return $query;
}


add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't work for me, though. All posts still show up in the pagination.

Comment: Sometimes changes in taxonomy require a flush chache in wordpress, you can do this in Settings, Permalinks then just click "Save" without changing anything. I have tested this code on different themes on several servers, it always worked. However this is a rule in functions.php that can be blocked by another code in any other file.